# Retrieve characters from a string

Tags: java

What is the best way to get a list of characters [a-z] from a string ignoring any other special character or number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```
String lettersOnly = original.replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
```

or

```
String lettersOnly = original.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
```

While you can use Unicode groups too, I personally find it easier to recognise and understand a simple set such as a-z or a-zA-Z - it means I don't need to look up whether it will include non-ASCII characters :)

Comment: I wouldn't have thought an upper case character qualified as a special character. ;)

Comment: @Peter: I was just going from the a-z in the post. Will edit for other options...

Answer (score 3):

Limiting yourself to `a-z` might remove characters you want. e.g. it remove uppercase and letters other than a-z.  You might prefer to try

```
String alphaOnly = text.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha}]", "");
```

This includes upper and lower case letters from any language.